# Angular js how to pass data to delete service?

Tags: angularjs, service

I am working in angular js on delete service api when passing data in service it is showing 400 bad request error.This is my js to call the service.

```
$scope.deleteUser = function(id){ 
    var data = 'Id='+id;   

     DataService.deleteUser(data).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('deleted'); 
    }, function errorCallback(response) { 
            console.log(response);

    }); 

}
```

This is service js to delete users.

```
service.deleteUser = function(data){ 
                var config = {
                    headers:  {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                        'X-Auth-Token': 'mytoken'
                    } 
                };
                return $http.delete(mainURL + '/users', data, config); 
};
```

This is curl api request where i need to pass data:

`curl -v -H "X-Auth-Token: mytoken" -X DELETE -F Id=665799088   http://<ipaddress>/users`

Comment: According to documention [delete method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#delete) on $http service only accepts 2parameters, url and config, meaning that your data is currently treated like config. You are most likely looking to pass some params options to your config object.

Comment: How are you accepting 'Id' in your API? Are you getting it from the body of the request?

Comment: Also, not sure if you have your hands on this, but I think it would be more correct if the id was part of the url something like delete on `/users/id`.

Comment: I am passing it as query string.

Comment: If you are passing any kind of secure information a message body is absolutely critical, as it will be encrypted when using HTTPS. Since the DELETE method does not support a body you would need to use a standard POST.

Comment: I have tried to pass the id as parameters in config but getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter to $http.delete is the config, so you need to pass the config object as the 2nd parameter and not data.

DELETE method type doesn't accept a Request body so you should not be passing the ID as data. Instead try this http://main_url/users?Id=id

So in your service use this

```
return $http.delete(mainURL + '/users?Id='+data, config);
```

Also check how you are passing the ID to your API. If you are passing ID as a query parameter then the above will work, but if you are passing it as a route parameter then the above URL won't work, but from your CURL expression I believe you are passing Id in the Query string and not as a route parameter.

Comment: i have tested it to pass the id as a query string.When i hit the curl service in command prompt then it return's response without any error.

Comment: Are you getting a bad request even when you modify the delete state like I showed above. Alternatively try this as well return $http.delete(mainURL + '/users/'+data, config); Some APIs take the ID as a default route parameter.

Comment: If delete method was impossible on `/users` the return code would be more like 405 I guess.

Comment: dear god, please don't place ids or other potentially secure information in the URL as a query parameter. That information will exist as plain text in logs in numerous systems that pass that data along its route from the client to the server. Even when using HTTPS!

Comment: I have also tried to pass the id tn the url like this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#delete) on `$http` service,  delete method only accepts 2 parameters, url and config, meaning that your data is currently treated like config. You are most likely looking to pass some params options to your config object.

```
DataService.deleteUser(id).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log('deleted'); 
}, function errorCallback(response) { 
        console.log(response);

});
```

And your service declaration should be more like.

```
service.deleteUser = function(id){ 
                var config = {
                    headers:  {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                        'X-Auth-Token': 'mytoken'
                    },
                    params : { 
                        id : id 
                    }
                };
                return $http.delete(mainURL + '/users', config); 
            };
```

Also keep in mind that a path looking like `/users/id` is more correct, if you are in charge of the API.

Comment: This also needs the caveat about placing secure information in the URL. If the id is something like an SSN then this information will be log on multiple system as plain text, even when using HTTPS.

Comment: When i tried to pass params in config then it is showing error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" in firebug.

Comment: Then you can add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to your config headers attribute.

Comment: @enzey IMO the id is there to identify and manage users throughout the api in a restful kind of way, so yeah the id is in the url. You can find more information about how exposing resource over HTTP according to REST practices [there](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-i-explained-rest-my-wife-jason-roell)